# Drop down of week no with date range issue

Tags: php, date

i want to show drop down of current and following week number of the year with date range.

i have used this code

```
  for ($i = $j; ($i <= $j + 1) && ($i <= 52); $i++) {
    $str = '';
    if (in_array($i, $week_no_array)) {
        $str ='selected = "selected"';
    }
    ?>

        <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>" <?php echo $str; ?> >
        <?php
    $year = date('Y');

    $week_start_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($year . "W" . $i . '1'));
    $week_end_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($year . "W" . $i . '7'));

    echo $i . ' (' . $week_start_date . ' - ' . $week_end_date . ')'
    ?>
        </option>
```

But for today’s date(30-12-2013) its showing wrong week range because it takes year 2013 but week no is 1 of 2014.

Comment: This week __is__ week 1 of 2014. It isn't clear if you think it shouldn't be, or if you know that it is, but your code returns 2013. Could you clarify please?

Answer (score 1):

Change your line:

```php
$year = date('Y');
```

with:

```php
$year = date('o');
$i = sprintf('%02d', $i);
```

<sup>In your foreach loop you have condition `$i <= 52`, which is not OK, since years can also have 53 weeks (in every 400 years there are 71 years with 53 weeks).</sup>

<kbd>[**DateTime demo**](https://eval.in/84201)</kbd>

Comment: thanks,but i want to show previous 3 weeks also,so where i have to changed in code.